# ¿Cómo se podría haber realizado este "cuadro" en CSS?

Tags: css

¿Cómo se podría haber realizado este "cuadro" en CSS? Con un grid o quizás con una tabla?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No tengo claro como se haria este tipo de "caja" dentro de un div, si es que se hace con un grid o quizás con una tabla o algo similar, alguien sabe y me puede orientar un poco? gracias.

Comment: ¿Probaste las opciones que mencionas? ¿Qué encontraste al probarlas? ¿Cómo las probaste? Qué problema tuviste al probarlas?

Answer (score 1):

Amigo aqui resolvemos codigo, pero aqui te dejo algo parecido a lo que necesitas echo con BootStrap.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>NOTA MEDIA</title>
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-lg-6 text-center">
            <table class="table table-primary table-sm">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="col">Ticker</th>
                  <th scope="col">Invested</th>
                  <th scope="col">Current</th>
                  <th scope="col">Gain</th>
                  <th scope="col"></th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <th>$BTC</th>
                  <td><input type="" name="" value="150" class="rounded-pill text-center"></td>
                  <td><input type="" name="" value="235" class="rounded-pill text-center"></td>
                  <td>+ 85 €</td>
                  <td><button class="btn-primary rounded-pill">Delete</button></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th>$CRO</th>
                  <td><input type="" name="" value="50" class="rounded-pill text-center"></td>
                  <td><input type="" name="" value="55" class="rounded-pill text-center"></td>
                  <td>+ 5 €</td>
                  <td><button class="btn-primary rounded-pill">Delete</button></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th>$ETH</th>
                  <td><input type="" name="" value="0" class="rounded-pill text-center"></td>
                  <td><input type="" name="" value="100" class="rounded-pill text-center"></td>
                  <td>+ 100 €</td>
                  <td><button class="btn-primary rounded-pill">Delete</button></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th>$MATIC</th>
                  <td><input type="" name="" value="310" class="rounded-pill text-center"></td>
                  <td><input type="" name="" value="460" class="rounded-pill text-center"></td>
                  <td>+ 150 €</td>
                  <td><button class="btn-primary rounded-pill">Delete</button></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th>$SHIT</th>
                  <td><input type="" name="" value="0" class="rounded-pill text-center"></td>
                  <td><input type="" name="" value="10" class="rounded-pill text-center"></td>
                  <td>+ 10 €</td>
                  <td><button class="btn-primary rounded-pill">Delete</button></td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tu respuesta es solo codigo. Por favor mira [answer]. Se pide que expliques que hace este código (mas alla que a ti vos te parezca obvio, puede que otro usuario no lo vea tan simple).